# Simple shell with pipe( ) function

Tags: c, bash, shell

I am writing a simple code to implement the pipe function for a unix/linux shell.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void
cisshPipe(char* command1[], char* command2[])

{
  int fd[2];//create array for two file descritors 
  pid_t childPid;//To set for child process
  pipe(fd);//To create pipeline here

  if((childPid=fork())==-1)
  {
       perror("fork here");
       exit(1);
  }

//The below is the real meat for this subroutine
  if(childPid==0)//If child process
  {
     close(fd[0]);//To close the input of child
     dup(fd[0]);//To duplicate the input, for the later process
  }
  else//For the real output
  {
    close(fd[1]);//To close the parent output first
    execvp(command2[],command2);
  }

  }
```

However, I got some compilation error on "execvp(command2[],command2)" for expected expression here. I think it is due to the dup() function that I use to pass the child output to parent input. Any suggestions to fix it please?

Some update:

Thanks for the answer from John. I fix the problem of compilation. But it is performing the pipe function when I type "ls | sort", I think it is still the passing of dup() problem here.

Comment: Please post the exact message. The error is what tells you what is wrong...

Comment: Did you read the documentation of the functions you are calling, e.g. [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html)? You should invoke it as documented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works, but doesn't do all the possible error checking.  Similarly to the way you need to close a file descriptor after redirecting standard input from (or standard output to) a file, when you're using pipes, if you `dup()` or `dup2()` one end of the pipe to standard input or output, you need to close both ends of the pipe afterwards, before executing the command.  When the pipe is created in a parent process that survives the children, you need to ensure that both ends of the pipe are closed in the parent too.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static inline void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

static void
cisshPipe(char **command1, char **command2)
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t childPid;
    if (pipe(fd) != 0)
        error("failed to create pipe");

    if ((childPid = fork()) == -1)
        error("failed to fork");

    if (childPid == 0)
    {
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(command1[0], command1);
        error("failed to exec command 1");
    }
    else
    {
        dup2(fd[0], 0);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execvp(command2[0], command2);
        error("failed to exec command 2");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char *ls[] = { "ls", 0 };
    char *sort[] = { "sort", "-r", 0 };
    cisshPipe(ls, sort);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
xx.dSYM
xx.c
xx
xma.dSYM
xma.c
xma
ws-c11.c
…
am-pm.pl
2dv.dSYM
2dv.c
2dv
2da.dSYM
2da.c
2da
```

Answer (score 3):

```
execvp(command2[],command2);
```

An empty `[]` is a syntax error. Perhaps you meant:

```
execvp(command2[0], command2);
```