# How to tokenize sentences with symbols in C

Tags: c, bash, unix, pipe, execvp

I'm trying to figure out how to tokenize Unix commands but I do not know how to work around the fact that `strtok()` splits any character you have as the delimiter. E.g. `strtok(string, ". ")` will remove the period AND the space.

The string I'm trying to have tokenize might be something like `ps aux( sort ( more` and there are spaces before and after the parenthesis.

Even if I do `strtok(string, "(")` there's still whitespace before or after the words and apparently `execvp()` doesn't recognize those tokens. E.g

```
ps aux 
 sort
 more
```

The output I'm expecting is

```
ps aux
sort
more
```

Are there any other functions that allow specific inputs like `" ( "` for it to be split for tokens?

Comment: Just write a simple function to remove leading whitespaces from each string.

Comment: The larger issue is what you are calling `"("` parenthesis, should actually be *pipes*, e.g. `'|'` tying the `stdout` from the prior command (e.g. `ps aux`) to the `stdin` for `sort`. This you have to handle using pipes in C as well and involves more than simply tokenizing the string to send to `execvp`. I'll see if I can find the duplicate for that question..

Comment: See [Pipe function in Linux shell write in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156341/pipe-function-in-linux-shell-write-in-c) and [Simple shell with pipe( ) function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788603/simple-shell-with-pipe-function)

Comment: It's possible that `strtok()` is not the correct function to be using.  It certainly isn't the function I'd be using because it zaps the delimiter.  Look up `strspn()` and `strcspn()` — they can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `strtok` for this, it is not the right tool for accurate parsing.

You can use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to scan the string for separators without modifying the string.

Here is a simplistic example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void parse_line(const char *buf) {
    int pos, len;

    for (pos = 0; buf[pos]; pos += len) {
        len = strspn(buf + pos, " \t\r\n");     // skip blanks
        if (len > 0) {
            continue;
        }
        len = strspn(buf + pos, "<>|&[]()");
        if (len > 0) {
            printf("operator %.*s\n", len, buf + pos);
            continue;
        }
        if (buf[pos] == '\'') {
            len = 1 + strcspn(buf + pos + 1, "'");
            if (buf[pos + len] != '\'') {
                printf("unterminated string: %.*s\n", len, buf + pos);
                break;
            }
            len += 1;
            printf("string: %.*s\n", len, buf + pos);
            continue;
        }
        if (buf[pos] == '\"') {
            len = 1 + strcspn(buf + pos + 1, "\"");
            if (buf[pos + len] != '\"') {
                printf("unterminated string: %.*s\n", len, buf + pos);
                break;
            }
            len += 1;
            printf("string: %.*s\n", len, buf + pos);
            continue;
        }
        len = strcspn(buf + pos, "\'\" \t\r\n<>|&[]()");
        printf("token: %.*s\n", len, buf + pos);
    }
}

int main() {
    char buf[128];

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        parse_line(buf);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

- You want to split a line on a left paren `(`.
- The left paren may be preceded and/or followed by a whitespace.
  (judging from your input, there are no whitespaces between `aux` and the following left paren)

Then how about an `awk` solution:

```
str="ps aux( sort ( more"
awk -F ' *\\( *' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' <<< "$str"
```

Output:

```
ps aux
sort
more
```

- The `-F` option determines the input field separator.
- The pattern `' *\\( *'` is a regex which matches a left paren
  with 0 or more whitespaces before and/or after it.

If my assumption is incorrect, please let me know.

**[EDIT]**

If you prefer a `C` solution, following code will be a help to start:

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    regex_t    preg;
    char       *string = "ps aux( sort ( more";
    char       *pattern = " *\( *";    // regex of the delimiter
    char       out[256];               // output buffer
    int        rc;
    size_t     nmatch = 1;
    regmatch_t pmatch[1];

    // compile the regex
    if (0 != (rc = regcomp(&preg, pattern, 0))) {
        printf("regcomp() failed, returning nonzero (%d)\n", rc);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // loop while the regex of delimiter is found
    while (0 == (rc = regexec(&preg, string, nmatch, pmatch, 0))) {
        strncpy(out, string, pmatch[0].rm_so);  // copy the substring to print
        out[pmatch[0].rm_so] = 0;       // terminate the string
        printf("%s\n", out);
        string += pmatch[0].rm_eo;      // seek the pointer to the start of the next token
    }
    // print the last remaining portion
    if (strlen(string) > 0) {
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }
    regfree(&preg);
    return 0;
}
```

[Explanation]
If `regexec()` succeeds, it returns the "start position of the matched
substring" in `pmatch[0].rm_so` and the "next to end position of the matched
substring" in `pmatch[0].rm_eo` as follows:

```
1st call of regexec()
string:  ps aux( sort ( more
               ^ ^
           rm_so rm_eo
```

We can interpret them as: `pmatch[0].rm_so` holds the length of the 1st token
and `pmatch[0].rm_eo` indicates the start position of the next token.
Then we update the variables and invoke the 2nd `regexec()`:

```
2nd call of regexec()
string:  sort ( more
             ^  ^
         rm_so  rm_eo
```

We repeat the loop until `regexec()` returns a non-zero value, meaning
no more match. Then the last token will remain in `string`.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, (ANSI) C does not have any more powerful tools than that, but if you must use it, you could give it a try with regex library, only you might have to do some of the work yourself (I don't know if GNULib has a regex_replace_all functionality for example).

You might want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1085083/2218762).

An inventory of regex libs and more about this topic can also be found [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html).

PS: *This should rather be a comment, but I don't have the rights to write one*

Comment: Actually it does: `strspn()` and `strcspn()` from `<string.h>` return the number of characters in the token and do not modify the string. Elaborate parsing such as handling escape sequences requires more code but these often overlooked functions are a good tool to get started.